# Why this difference between the local response norm paper equation and tensorflow implementation?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I came across this equation in Alex's [paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf) on local response normalization:
  [image]

As we see above, the power is raised after we calculate the sum, multiply it with alpha and then add once k is added.

However, I see in TensorFlow documentation it is showed as

```
sqr_sum[a, b, c, d] =
  sum(input[a, b, c, d - depth_radius : d + depth_radius + 1] ** 2)
output = input / (bias + alpha * sqr_sum ** beta)
```

where the beta is raised only for the sum.

Why is there a discrepancy here?

Also, when I looked into the TensorFlow code itself, I saw this:

```
output[b, r, c, d] /= (
            np.power(bias + alpha * np.sum(patch * patch), beta))
```

which looks correct?

I am kind of confused here. Can someone correct me please?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the paper.

Comment: Please see section 3.3 here https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjd5o68p6TKAhXGhhoKHf8kCR4QFggeMAA&usg=AFQjCNFstmTp69V5D8OpmvXnc3MJ4sVstw

Comment: Thanks. I'll add it to the question for others.

Comment: Looks like a glitch in the docs?

Comment: TensorFlow code [Local Response Normalization](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/ops/nn_ops.cc#L272)

Comment: TensorFlow documentation [tf.nn.local_response_normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/nn.html#local_response_normalization)

Comment: TensorFlow test code [LRNOpTest](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/lrn_op_test.py#L46)

Comment: @GuyCoder yes, these are the same references I made.

Comment: Just making it easier for others to find the info and trace back to the source.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in the Tensorflow documentation.

It was fixed by this commit on Feb 26:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/ab48dbd4ac2095548a5bc8505e08e751d409727f#diff-632987400e5affbcdba4533444460b0e